# PowerQuery in Excel 'master' spreadsheet on SharePoint can only be refreshed by one user and gives authentication errors for others

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, authentication, sharepoint, power-query

I created a group of SharePoint libraries on an intranet that each contain an identically formatted spreadsheet, and another library that contains a “Master” spreadsheet that fills a table from the data entered into each of the other libraries' spreadsheets.

The Master spreadsheet works and can be updated from my account and can be accessed by other users, but when other users try to refresh the data, they are given an authentication error.

All three other users that were unable to refresh the data have access to all the spreadsheets and can open them either in SharePoint, or by navigating to the SharePoint site's folder, and I verified that the 'credentials' settings were the same across all four users.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem - I just hadn't set the credentials correctly to all of the queries.

My final query was made of multiple queries which were combined together, and the credential update had only been applied to the combined query. After manually setting the credentials for each of the other queries for other users in Excel, they were able to update successfully.